# Instruction error while learning assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

So I'm trying to learn some x86 assembly, I'm using NASM as my complier. I have [this code](http://pastebin.com/uDUyVr1d) that I'm working on, but when I compile, I get an error.

```
$ nasm -f bin -o myfirst.bin myfirst.asm
myfirst.asm:46: error: parser: instruction expected
```

Any idea whats wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you typed 'mv' instead of 'mov' on line 46

Comment: Well crap. Guess I've been doing too much Linux sysadmin stuff, ha.